# what does the second derivative of a linear function mean?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives

So if I have a function

```
f(x) = 7x-2
```

the first derivative is

```
7
```

which I'm inclined to think that the second derivative exists because

```
7 = 0x+7
```

and the second derivative is

```
0
```

makes sense, I guess, because the slope never ever changes.
But how am I supposed to put that into context with the rest of the info available? There is no concaving up or down in either direction (though I can imagine it being a really straight curve) and if all I knew was the first and second derivatives, I might just think I'm at an inflection point and that there's a horizon somewhere else.  This might be a moot point since I'm likely always gonna have the original function at hand in the real world but I was wondering if anyone else had any thoughts on the derivatives of a straight line.  Maybe the second derivative doesn't exist?

Comment: What do you mean by putting it into context? The second derivative definitely exists and is zero everywhere. This just means (in an intuitive sense) that there is no curvature to the graph at any point.

Comment: doesn't a quadratic graph have at least one point where the second derivative is 0?

Comment: Generally not. For a quadratic $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, the second derivative is $2a$, which is zero only if $a$ is zero, in which case most people wouldn't call $f$ a quadratic equation in the first place.

Comment: @jollarvia, the curvature of a parabola is constant. Even intuitively, why would there be a point where the second derivative  is zero? The slope of the tangent line either always increases or always decreases.

Comment: Ok that explains a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @A.P. well, there's a point where the tangent slope is definitely negative and a point where the tangent slope is definitely positive.  Somewhere in between there's a 0.

Comment: Yes, but this is a point where the **first** derivative is zero, not the second.

Comment: for a function where the second derivative is positive, am I to expect that the first derivative always increases with respect to x no matter where I am in the graph? For a function with a cubic term my second derivative looks something like 2x+3.  Is there a such thing as a third derivative that says that on average over the whole graph my first derivative should accelerate up constantly?

Comment: @jollarvia if you want the first derivative to be linear in $x$, then the second derivative will be constant, and the third derivative will be zero. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. There are derivatives of all orders, each representing the rate of change of the derivative of order one less.

Comment: well I meant in my last comment about adding a cubic term where the third derivative is a constant: 2.  Does that mean that despite the multiple curving of the graph that the first derivative always accelerates up?

Comment: Ok thanks @qaphla. That was very helpful

Answer (score 2):

The information you get is when you only have $f''(x)=0$ then you now that $f$ is a *linear function*, because this is an "if and only if"-relation.

That is: If $f(x)$ is linear, then $f''(x)=0$.
And: If $f''(x)=0$, then $f(x)$ is linear.

That reads: $f(x)$ is linear $\leftrightarrow$ $f''(x)=0$

Comment: So the zero function is considered linear?

Comment: Why wouldn't the zero function be considered linear? I suppose the term "zero function" could have different meanings in different contexts. In this context it seems reasonable to infer that we are talking more precisely about the zero polynomial, which is clearly linear both by intuition and definition. A more general concept of linear, i.e. $af(x+y)=af(x)+af(y)$, is also true for the zero polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

The zero function, that is $f(x)=0$, is a special case of linear function. Suppose the linear function has the form $f(x)=k*x+d$, then the zero function has $k=0$ and $d=0$.

Of course, also $f''(x)=0$ is true in this case. Nevertheless, keep in mind, that a zero function is a linear function, so the statement that $f''(x)=0$ implies that $f(x)$ is linear holds.